# In Python, if I print a zip object casted to a set (print(set(zip_object))) twice in a row I get => set( ) as the second result. Why?

Tags: python, casting, set, zip

Given a zip object created from two lists:

 `print(set(zip_object))`

 `print(set(zip_object))`

 Yields two different results. The second result is: `set( )`. Why?

In learning about Python's zip function I followed the two examples:

1. https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp
2. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zip-in-python/

One example shows the results of zip by casting the object to a tuple, the other by casting to a set. I noticed when I attempted to print the casted zip_object twice in a row, I got two different results.

Similar "errors" occur whether I cast to **tuple** , **set**, or  **list**, so which data type I'm casting to doesn't seem to matter.

If I store the casted results into a new variable 
(`a = set(zip_object`), 
instead of printing directly,
`print(a)`
`print(a)`
 
produces identical results, as expected. So this error may have to do with the zip object being overwritten in memory?

Directly printing a casted, **non-zipped** list, tuple or set, twice, produces expected results. So it has something to do with the zip function.

Given the code:

```
courses = ['History', 'Math', 'Physics', 'CompSci']
period = [1, 2, 3, 4]
schedule = zip(period, courses)
print(set(schedule))
print(set(schedule))
```

**Expected:**

=> {(4, 'CompSci'), (1, 'History'), (2, 'Math'), (3, 'Physics')}

=> {(4, 'CompSci'), (1, 'History'), (2, 'Math'), (3, 'Physics')}

**Actual:**

=> {(4, 'CompSci'), (1, 'History'), (2, 'Math'), (3, 'Physics')}

=> set( )

Why do we get `set( )`?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `zip` is not a function; it's a *type* (though it is callable like virtually every other type so that `zip(...)` creates an instance without having to call `zip.__new__` directly).

Comment: `zip` returns an iterator which can be iterated through once to exhaustion. Data types like lists are sequences which can be iterated over many times by producing, for example, a `list_iterator` object.

Comment: The Python documentation calls `zip()` a function (https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html), which returns an object of type zip.

Answer (score 2):

You are exhausting the iterator; it doesn't reset between calls to `set`. Effectively, `set` calls `next` on the iterator until `StopIteration` is raised. The *next* call to `set` starts with an iterator on which the *first* call to `next` raises `StopIteration`.